# How to invoke hook_node_submit for custom content type

Tags: drupal-7, cck

I am trying to run some basic php whenever a node of a specific content type is saved. What's the best way to do this? Is hook_node_submit even the proper function, and if so, how should it be invoked?

This is a CCK content type and not one created through a custom module.

Comment: Question is not clear, can you explain what you want to accomplish running "php" code?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sure: I have a bunch of fields associated with the CT, and what I need to do is count how many of them have values every time the node is updated. If it exceeds a certain threshold, a flag is set to true so that the node will appear in certain search results. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
hook_node_presave($node)
```

This hook is invoked from node_save() before the node is saved to the database.

Comment: Thanks! But *where* is the best place to implement that?

Comment: You can implement in any module file you want as modulename_node_presave($node);

Comment: Ok I will give it a shot